# creating linestring from series of numbers separated by comma

Tags: postgresql, line

How can i generate a linestring with a sql question from this source of numbers, where all coordinate items are separated with comma:

```
[16.49422,48.8011,16.49432,48.8012,16.49441,48.80127,16.49451,48.80131,16.49464,48.80135,16.49471,48.80139]
```

Linestring should be separated by each second number with comma.

```
LINESTRING(16.49422 48.8011,1 6.49432 48.8012, ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a function for this, as it makes the actual SQL that has to convert the JSON array to the "string" a lot easier to deal with:

```
create function jsonb_array_to_linestring(p_input jsonb)
  returns text
as
$$
declare
  l_num_elements int;
  l_idx int;
  l_result text;
begin
  l_num_elements := jsonb_array_length(p_input);
  if l_num_elements = 2 then 
    return 'point('||(p_input ->> 0)||' '||(p_input ->> 1)||')';
  end if;
  l_result := 'linestring(';
  for l_idx in 0 .. l_num_elements - 2 by 2 loop
    l_result := l_result || (p_input ->> l_idx) || ' ' || (p_input ->> l_idx + 1);
    if l_idx < l_num_elements - 2 then 
      l_result := l_result || ',' ;
    end if;
  end loop;
  l_result := l_result || ')';
  return l_result;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select id, jsonb_array_to_linestring(input)
from test;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d9284b8fd9285a0a2d0032de7c9ab0b0)

This assumes your column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If you are using `json` instead, you need to adjust the code to that.

Comment: it sounds smarter. how should i change the part of the function, when i must decide between points or linestrings. points = 1 pair of coordinates, linestrings > 1 pair of coordinates

Comment: the function don't sort the values, so the result is not equal to the input. input begin with 16.49422,48.8011,16.49432,48.8012 the result is ... 16.49422 48.80139,48.8011 16.49422

Comment: sorry, it should be sorted otherwise i become a not valid geometry. the linestring should be build in the sort of the source.

Comment: @Tibor: a sorry, the code was intended to add the elements in the order they appear in the array. But the array access was wrong. See my edit

Comment: now it works both point and linestring thx much. how can i create a scound if for l_num_elements = NULL - now i see in my data, that sometimes the coordinats are missing. resoult should be in that case NULL

Answer (score 0):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=480b1bdf54283259fa5ecbf25fd05b12)

```
SELECT
    st_makeline(point order by index)                    -- 6
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ceil(index::numeric / 2) as index,               -- 3
        st_makepoint(                                    -- 5
            MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE index % 2 = 1),     -- 4
            MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE index % 2 = 0)
        ) as point
    FROM 
        unnest(                                          -- 1
            ARRAY[16.49422,48.8011,16.49432,48.8012,16.49441,48.80127,16.49451,48.80131,16.49464,48.80135,16.49471,48.80139
        ]) WITH ORDINALITY elements(value, index)        -- 2
    GROUP BY 1                                           -- 3
) s
```

1. Extract all array elements into one record per element
2. This adds an index to the elements to store their position within the original index
3. Calculate the coordinate pairs. Here I used `ceil(... / 2)` to generate the same value for indexes: old index pair `(1, 2)` -> new index `1`, `(3, 4)` -> `2`, `(5, 6)` -> `3`, ... This can be used for grouping
4. Now we use a conditional aggregation to create two columns: One for the odd indexes and one for the even, to generate a X/Y pair for your coordinates.
5. These pairs can be used to create a `Point`
6. Afterwards all `Point`s can be merged into one line. To ensure the correct order, we use the recently created pair `index`.

If your input is not a normal Postgres array but a JSON array, you have to change 2 things ([demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=809da199a4ae94e8208807dc9e2c57f8)):

- In (1): `unnest(...)` to `json_array_elements_text(...)`
- In (4): `MAX(value)` to `MAX(value::numeric)`

Comment: OK, added a demo fiddle :)

Comment: Hi, s-man how dose it work's if the json array is a column and i have more rows. each row has his id. For example the table name is test and the two columns are 'id' and 'geoArray'. The column 'id' is text and the 'geoArray' is json 'i

Comment: Extended the query for your use case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b9173ce81a70f3890191268d02d96b61